# Retrieving variables from functions

Tags: functional-programming

Since generally variables inside functions have a local scope(I assume),what's the best way, in any functional language, to retrieve variables from functions, like that, in pseudo language

```
function test = (
firstVariable = calculateSomething()
secondVariable = calculateSomethingElse()
)

(
function finalCalculation = (
test() /*call the previously defined function*/
result = firstVariable+secondVariable /*how do I get those?*/
)
```

Edit: I'm not being general. This problem is applicable to all functional languages. The problem itself resides in the concept of retrieving a variable from another function, avoiding global scopes. Anyway, for sake of simplicity, and the structure of the example, let's say javascript.

Comment: specify the language please. don't spam with tags.

Comment: Put them in a global scope (field variable).

Comment: What is the "best" way is far to vague to get a good answer. Maybe the most common way is simply to let the function return its results.

Comment: "The problem itself resides in the concept..." There is no problem. There are already some answers and maybe you should consider to accept one of them or rephrase you question to make more clear what really is your "problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript the **IIFE** and **Closure** principles

```
var f = (function() {
    var localFunc = function(){};
    var localVar1 = 3;
    var localVar2 = 4;

    // publish
    return {
         localFunc: localFunc,
         localVar: localVar1 
    }
})();

f.localFunc(); // ok
f.localVar2;   // nok
```

I don't known if i answered the question

Answer (score 2):

Functions can return a result:

```
result function test = (
    result.firstVariable = calculateSomething()
    result.secondVariable = calculateSomethingElse()
    return result
)

function finalCalculation = (
    result = test()
)
```

However, this question smells like either you actually dont have any real problem at hand, or your actual problem is something else and you turned it into something too academic. Questions tagged as java,javascript,C and C++ rarely result in reasonable answers, as this languages are just too different in their details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a leak of fundamental knowledge. Key words are `global variables`, `return value`, and `getter/setter` : You should specify the languange you want to use and ask some concrete questions.